# ternary operator without else in C

Tags: c, operator-keyword, if-statement, ternary

I want to use ternary operator without else in C. How do I do it.

```
(a)? b: nothing;
```

something like this. What do I use in nothing part?

Comment: why use a ternary operator if you are not going to use else. It loses the purpose of it.

Comment: i got the same question as op, `cout << ((isNegative) ? '-') << number` would be a perfect example of where you would want an extra character when a certain condition is true, and the else cannot be '', because a character cannot be empty.

Comment: What is it meant to mean, and in what context do you want to use it?

Comment: @user5887651  One could use `(isNegative ? (cout<<',') : cout) << number;` I suppose...

Comment: maybe OP wanted to use the ternary operator as an expression, but it's quite interesting to think "so, what is *'nothing'* expression?"

Answer (score 60):

If you are using a ternary operator like that, presumably it could be replaced by:

```
if (a) { b; }
```

which is much, *much* better. (The intent is clearer, so the code is easier to read, and there will be no performance loss.)

However, if you are using the ternary operator as an expression, i.e.

```
printf("%d cat%s", number_of_cats, number_of_cats != 1 ? "s" : <nothing>);

a = b*c + (d == 0 ? 1 : <nothing>);
```

then the `<nothing>` value depends on the context it is being used in. In my first example, `<nothing>` should be `""`, and in the second it should be `0`.

Comment: suppose I need to call other macros depending on conditions and last else part doing nothing, can I write something like below (Assume A,B,C are defined elsewhere): #define setValue(inp) (inp==A)?macro1():(inp==B)?macro2() :(inp==C)?macro3():0. But here again if 0 is the valid return on other macros, we may have issues.

Comment: @JonWheelock: Just use multiline macros and `if` statements

Answer (score 29):

An omitted false expression is invalid.  Try reversing the condition instead.

```
(!a) ?: b;
```

Comment: Note that `?:` without the second operand is a GNU extension. The semantics probably don't provide an answer to the question, as the value of the first operand (`!a`) will be used if non-false, and that of the third operand (`b`) otherwise. Because of `!`, that would always be `true` (technically a non-zero value) if `a` is false, whereas the OP wants "nothing".

Answer (score 15):

`if-else` is a control flow construct wheras `?:` is an operator, and `x ? y : z` is an expression - an expression cannot have "no value", while control flow can have a "do nothing path".  There is no real equivalence between if-else and ?: - they are not interchangeable in all circumstances.

You can achieve the effect you want in *some* circumstances, but it is probably less efficient that using `if` without `else`.  For example the effect of:

```
if( x )
{
    y = z ;
}
```

can be achieved by:

```
y = x ? z : y ;
```

but there is an effective but redundant `else y = y` assignment when x is false which your compiler may or may not optimise out.  So you can achieve the effect but only if you know the "current value" to return as the `?:` expression result.

Answer (score 4):

You can't omit the `else` part. Just use a none expression.

But, in that case, it is often better to use an `if`...

Comment: HI thanks for reply. It complies now. I understood 0 but  dont understand what  (void) indicate to the compiler?

Comment: This necessitates that `b` also be of type `void`.

Comment: I thought ternary operator  is faster than if condition? Am I wrong?

Comment: @user437777, not really. It's still an `if`, except more compact. More importantly, it's an expression that can be used inside other expressions. Otherwise, it's still just an `if`.

Comment: Uhm, it is sometimes a little bit faster, but it's moot and irrelevant in mainly programs.

Comment: @userXXX it's a typecast - casting to void means 'throw away the result of the expression'.

Comment: Thanks all for reply. So I can use like (a)? (void)b:(void)0;               about the speed, this condition is used about 2^16 times inside my code, will it be helpful to use ternary then?

Comment: @user437777, the if and the ternary are likely to get compiled to the same code.

Comment: Benchmark? It depends on the situation, and on the optimization level.

Answer (score 3):

Seems this question has been around for a while, but FWIW a short C program compiled with GCC 4.6.3 revealed the following:

1. The following does not compile: `a = a ? b:;`. "error: expected expression before ‘;’ token".
2. The following is equivalent: `a = a ?: b;` and `a = a ? a : b;`

Perhaps someone can add more compiler-side details, but to me it seems that omitting the `true` execution path is just being fancy.

Answer (score 3):

I tried putting any integers there and it works well. For example, if you want to return "a" if it's evaluated true, then you can write it like:

```
true ? a : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this

`isLeapYear(i) ? cout<< i<<endl: cout<<""  ;`

Not sure though, if there is any performance hit with this.

Comment: You could have just done this with minimal perf hit.
cout << isLeapYear(i) ? i : "";

Answer (score 1):

Ternary expressions base themselves on deriving statements from boolean conditions. If a statement is marked `void()` then as you expect, nothing happens.

C++ code:

```
condition ? add(value) : void();
```

C code:

```
condition ? add(value) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I knew that expression must be true, otherwise program is in invalid state, but ternary operator fits better than regular `if()` statement, I used to do like this

```
condition ? value : throw;
```

And leave it as above or add specific exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of other forms `a ? b : nothing;` can be take.

Short circuit evaluation where `b` will only be evaluated if `a` is true:

```
a && b;
```

Ternary where the `nothing` expression is `(void)0`:

```
a ? b : (void)0;
```

Reversed ternary condition with a blank middle (may not be portable):

```
!a ? : b;
```

A simple `if` statement:

```
if (a) {
    b;
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Try this

```
BOOL bIsOK = (a == 5)?TRUE:FALSE;
```

Comment: Seriously? This isn't at all relevant to the question.

Comment: .. and even if it were relevant it is equivalent to just `BOOL blsOK = (a==5) ;`