# C++ Ternary If Statement - Wish to have no "else" part

Tags: c++, if-statement, ternary-operator

I was to `delete []` some allocated memory if a condition is met: The condition is that `double* m_x == nullptr`

I am trying to do this:

```
(m_x == nullptr) ? (delete [] m_x);
```

However the compiler requires that I have the "else part" after a `:` like so:

```
(m_x == nullptr) ? (delete [] m_x) : ;
```

But I don't have anything to put after the colon.

Is there a way around this? Apart from:

```
if(m_x == nullptr)
        delete [] m_x;
```

Thanks,

**EDIT**

I meant `if(m_x != nullptr)` sorry copied it wrong

Comment: What abot `m_x == nullptr && delete[] m_x;`?

Comment: Set it equal to itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260777/ternary-operator-without-else-in-c

Comment: The error is right at the start: the ternary conditional operator forms an *expression*, not a *statement*. If you want a statement, use `if`.

Comment: What? You want to delete a pointer if and only if it is a null pointer?

Comment: @jalf: It's called a "conditional no-op". Get with the times.

Comment: Please don't do this. Use the conditional expression to choose between two values. Use an `if` statement to conditionally execute a side effect. They are different for a reason.

Answer (score 11):

You probably meant `(m_x != nullptr)` as the condition? In that case, you can simplify

```
(m_x != nullptr) ? (delete [] m_x);
```

to

```
delete[] m_x;
```

because the `nullptr` check is performed internally by `delete` and `delete[]`, anyway.

If you really meant the condition `(m_x == nullptr)`, then you can just get rid of the entire statement, because deleting a pointer only if it is null is always a no-op. Please explain why you think you want this.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth - except that it doesn't do what the question asked for, which was to `delete` **only if** the pointer is null.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh, I didn't realize that. I suppose this is a typo in the question? I cannot imagine why anybody would want to delete a null pointer?

Comment: @FredOverflow - the code you wrote is probably right, but giving an answer that has different semantics really calls for an explicit statement that that's what's happening.

Answer (score 9):

Using an `if` statement is probably better anyway. Why is that not a good solution?

But if you insist on using the conditional operator, just use a dummy expression whose value can be ignored:

```
m_x == nullptr ? delete [] m_x : (void)0
```

`(void)0` is the simplest way to create an expression of type `void`, needed here to match the type of `delete [] m_x`.

But if it's not part of a larger expression, I can think of no good reason not to use an `if` statement:

```
if (m_x == nullptr) delete [] m_x;
```

But since `delete` on a null pointer does nothing, it's difficult to understand why you'd want to do this in the first place.

If your actual intent is to delete the pointer if it's *not* null, then you'd want:

```
if (m_x != nullptr) delete [] m_x;
```

But again, since `delete` on a null pointer does nothing (thanks to @juanchopanza) for pointing that out in a comment), you might as well simplify it to:

```
delete [] m_x;
```

Comment: There is no need for this though. `delete [] m_x;` would be way simpler.

Comment: The idea of using zero doesn't work: Error is: error: second operand to the conditional operator is of type ‘void’, but the third operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type ‘void’

Comment: @EdwardBird: I've updated my answer, changing `0` to `(void)0`. But *please* read the rest of the answer (and the other answers and comments) as well. You have your logic backwards, and even allowing for that, there's probably no good reason to use a conditional operator rather than an `if` statement.

Answer (score 7):

The ternary operator is meant to be used in expressions, where you want to choose what value to return depending on a condition. It is a an `if` statement in the style of a functional language.

It is not meant to be used when you purely have side effects (such as freeing memory). Using an `if` statement is the right thing to do in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are using that properly...  Here is an example of how that statement is used...

```
int inValue = 5;
int i = 0;
int b = (inValue > 0) ? (i + 1) : (i);
```

It either assigns X or Y  Result=(condition)?X:Y